# Flex Alert.styleName not working for me

Tags: css, apache-flex, alert

I have this code, but the style is not being applied.  I've seen [articles on the web](http://flexonblog.wordpress.com/2008/01/01/applying-styles-to-alert-boxto-every-alert-box-and-to-a-particular-alert-box/) where this should work.  Any ideas?

```
var alert:Alert = Alert.show("You have not saved you changes.\n\nWould you like to save now?",
                             "Save Answers?",
                             Alert.NO | Alert.YES | Alert.CANCEL, 
                             this, 
                             handleUnsavedChanges,
                             null, 
                             Alert.YES);

alert.styleName = "alertStyle";
```

Attempting to set the style using the Alert class in my stylesheet seems to work, but throws a warning.  I'd like to find the "approved" way.

BTW, this is Flex 3.

PS - I've also tried stuff like

```
alert.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x00FF00");
```

but this does not seem to work either.  I feel like I need to call something to tell the Alert box to redraw itself, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom class in order to use specific css:

```
public class CustomAlert extends Alert {}
```

... Then in the CSS

```
CustomAlert 
{
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

Or a little more complicated example:

```
        import mx.styles.StyleManager;
        private function init():void {
            alertCSS = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("Alert");
        }

        private function showAlert(color:Object):void {
            alertCSS.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x00FF00");
            alert = Alert.show("The quick brown fox...");
        }
```

Comment: Two comments:  1.) I don't want to style all the alerts, just this one in particular.  2.) I already mentioned that this approach produces a compiler warning (CSS type selectors are not supported in components: 'Alert')

Comment: This is an "id10t" error.  For some reason, code to create the same exact alert box is duplicated in multiple places.  Not expecting this, I attempted to style the first one I came to (of course it was the wrong one).  Anyway, it appears that all these approaches will work - even setting the CSS styleName on the already create alert box.